# Proving government expenditure crowds out private consumption

Tags: microeconomics

[image]

Please help as I am not able to solve either parts.

Comment: Where do you have problems in a)? Can you get dY/dG?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know where exactly you have the problems, I
'm just providing a rough solution scheme here. Note that it's quite long ago that I did this stuff, so I may be outright wrong - *don't follow without verifying that the following actually makes sense*.

### a)

Since $Y = F(L)$ is increasing in $L$, the sign of $dY/dG$ is equal to the sign $dL/dG$. Through the government's budget constraint, any change in $G$ must be reflected in an increase in $M$ and/or an increase in $PT$.

Set up $\max_{C,L} U $ subject to the household's budget constraint, and then replace in the FOC $M - \bar M$ with $PG - PT$ , to get the dependence of $L$ on $G$. As soon as you have $L(G)$, you can compute $Y(G)$ as $F(L(G))$.

The next step then is just to look at the derivative of $d F(L(G))/dG$. Once you have $L(G)$, computing $C(G)$ is analogous.